# Crosstalk and Aggregated Data

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard, htmlwidgets

I am trying to create a flexdashboard that includes a Data Table along with Crosstalk Filters. My data includes similar data that I would like to aggregate to find the means of certain categories according to filter criteria. Basically, the table will be aggregated data.

It is my understanding that Crosstalk wasn't meant to aggregate data, but does anyone know a way around this? I'm willing to look at any way possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `summaryWidget` package
[link to github page](https://github.com/kent37/summarywidget)

Comment: Any idea on how to display this aggregated data into a plotly plot?